# What is the Bash equivalent of Python's pass statement

Tags: python, bash, language-comparisons

Is there a Bash equivalent to the Python's `pass` statement?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can use `:` for this.

Comment: More info: [Stack Overflow: What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Answer (score 53):

`true` is a command that successfully does nothing.

(`false` would, in a way, be the opposite: it doesn't do anything, but claims that a failure occurred.)

Comment: In other words, it does nothing, and fails at it.

Comment: @Ignacio: I was struggling with the language there: Can "it fails at doing nothing" be interpreted as "it, erroneously, does something"? ...Probably I'm just scared by things like the subtle differences between "undefined" and "unspecified" in C++.

Comment: By the way there is a `man true` and a `man false`.