# How to undo the effect of "set -e" which makes bash exit immediately if any command fails?

Tags: bash, exit

After entering `set -e` in an interactive bash shell, bash will exit immediately if any command exits with non-zero. How can I undo this effect?

Answer (score 376, accepted):

With `set +e`.  Yeah, it's backward that you *enable* shell options with `set -` and *disable* them with `set +`.  Historical raisins, donchanow.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's among the very last lines of corresponding manual page (http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_56.html) which I didn't read to the end.

Comment: The bash manual is dauntingly huge, it is true.  (FYI, since you seem to be new: it is the done thing to click the check mark under the best answer to your question, this is called "accepting" it.)

Comment: And the format `set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [argument ...]` is really misleading. I simply assumed the undo is done by another builtin, tried unset and got nothing. It's interesting that in bash `set` and `unset` are not opposite, while I admit I currently know little about bash programming.

Comment: Sadly, the Unix shell language (most of which is not specific to 'bash') is one of the least internally consistent programming languages still in wide use today.  You're going to have to learn lots more of these little warts.   And I'd say that's a documentation bug, there.

Comment: When I was about to report this documentation bug to GNU, I found that the bash manual hosted in faqs.org is last updated 13 November 2001... This bug is actually non-existent in current manual. But faqs.org's SEO seems better so I was mislead. I'll report it to faqs.org then.

Comment: historical grapes are raisin hell!

Comment: Finally, an unfair bashing of Bash: single dash is the standard POSIX shell command line option, and therefore most natural for "do something". `+` is like `-` but crossing over something means "not" as in "≠".

Comment: Bash is truly the worst

Answer (score 71):

It might be unhandy to use `set +e`/`set -e` each time you want to override it. I found a simpler solution.

Instead of doing it like this:

```
set +e
command_that_might_fail_but_we_want_to_ignore_it
set -e
```

you can do it like this:

```
command_that_might_fail_but_we_want_to_ignore_it || true
```

or, if you want to save keystrokes and don't mind being a little cryptic:

```
command_that_might_fail_but_we_want_to_ignore_it || :
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Was wondering about the history of `:`, and found my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/1094541), in case anyone else is curious.

Comment: This applies only if you don't care about the return code of the command you're running.

Answer (score 21):

> - Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.

[Source](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uset.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
(set +e; command_that_might_fail_but_we_want_to_continue_anyway)
```