# Conditionally do make distclean

Tags: bash, gnu-make, autotools

As part of a bash script, which has `set -e`, I do `make distclean` which, obviously, fails with the following error, if I have run distclean before calling the script:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'. Stop
```

Is there way to do distclean and not fail **if there's nothing to clean**?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is distclean? Is it some custom command, what does it do?

Comment: @kiner_shah It's a common target with Autotools projects. See https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets. In a common `./configure && make && make install` setup `make distclean` will delete the `Makefile`, leaving only the `configure` script behind, which leads to the error in the question.

Comment: Do the answers to ["How to undo the effect of `set -e` which makes bash exit immediately if any command fails?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517162/how-to-undo-the-effect-of-set-e-which-makes-bash-exit-immediately-if-any-comm) and ["Bash ignoring error for a particular command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command) answer your question?

Comment: Avoiding `set -e` and adding your own fail messages is also better.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with the error message being printed, and just want to ignore the failure and keep going, a common idiom is to append `|| :`.

The general syntax here is `cmd1 || cmd2`. If `cmd1` fails then it runs `cmd2`. `:` is the (unusual) name of a command that always succeeds, so `|| :` has the effect of ignoring the first command's exit code.

```
make distclean || :
```

If you would rather not see an error message at all, you could check if the `Makefile` exists first:

```
if [[ -e Makefile ]]; then make distclean; fi
```

Comment: Error message can also be ignored with `2>/dev/null` or `>/dev/null 2>&1` if not enough.

Comment: As the `Makefile` is both the most characteristic artifact of having configured (and not dist-cleaned) the project and also the file whose absence is most directly related to the error, testing for the presence of that file before executing `make distclean` seems exactly the right thing to do to avoid the error the OP describes.

Comment: I do not want to swallow an unknown error with `||`. I will prefer the `-e Makefile `  option. Thanks John.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
make distclean || echo "(Error from make ignored)"
```

to make it explicit what's happening.