# "while :" vs. "while true"

Tags: bash

When you look at how infinite loops should be implemented, you mostly see this approach:

```
while :
do
  # loop infinitely
done
```

But I just don't understand the use of `:` here. Wouldn't it be better to use:

```
while true
do
  # loop infinitely
done
```

?

Comment: No colon needed after `true`, as `:` is a command, not syntax.

Comment: The second snippet "almost" works, you just need to add a semicolon: `while true; do`

Answer (score 127, accepted):

from manual:

> : [arguments]
>             No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing  any  specified
>             redirections.  A zero exit code is returned.

As this returns always zero therefore is is similar to be used as `true`

Check out this answer: [What Is the Purpose of the `:' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/702361)

Answer (score 43):

The colon is a [built-in command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) that does nothing, but returns 0 (success). Thus, it's shorter (and faster) than calling an actual command to do the same thing.

Comment: It's true. `i=0; time while true; do ((i++>100000)) && break; done` takes slightly longer than the colon version.

Comment: The difference has nothing to do with commands vs builtins, as they're both builtin. It's purely the additional number of characters bash is dealing with. `while : some gibberish`, still just using `:`, is slower than `true`. Compare this to an external command, like `while /bin/true`, which is literally a hundred times slower.

Comment: I found this question after a red herring due to differences between `while true` and `while 1` - it turns out `1` is aliased to `cd -` which was obviously passing but printing `~` (my cwd at the time.) One caveat with `:` I noticed after trying this out: the usual rules apply to `:`, so you need to end it with a semicolon (or a line break in cases like this one, where you have an unclosed block.) So, for a one-liner, you would write `while :; do ...; done` as opposed to `while :\n do ...\n done`. Really this is hardly a caveat.

Comment: @thatotherguy, almost all of my in-depth knowledge is about compiled languages - does the interpreter really re-parse everything as if it were seeing it for the first time? I would have thought that at the very least, aliases like `:` would be replaced the first time it was encountered. Is the anticipated scenario something like an alias or path changing in the middle of execution? I would have expected `while $(echo true) ...` to defer but never `while /bin/true` -- if `/bin/true` were found to be missing, it would fail without the need for reinterpretation.