# Writing a CLI command in terminal with a comment at the end

Tags: bash, comments

I realize, it's possible to use the `#` in shell scripts:

```
#we're about to do something because we want to
do_something();
```

It would be nice however to occasionally write a comment *inline* at the command prompt, and I haven't seen a way to do this:

```
owilliams@OWILL04833 ~/go/test-tools$ ls -la config*     #find all configuration files
error: ls: #find: No such file or directory
```

especially so it would go in `.bash_history` or `.zsh_history`.  Is this possible?

Comment: That works actually. Are you sure you are running `bash`?

Comment: hm, I am running `zsh`.  Is there an equivalent way to do it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670935/comments-in-command-line-zsh

Comment: instead of `#` you can often use `;: ` (must have a trailing space)