# Why this bash command doesn't work in ZSH?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, zsh

I transitioned to ZSH from Bash. While most of the commands run flawlessly, I am not able to run certain ones. This is the case:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gjf" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
#Extract the file name without extension
folder_name="${file%.*}"

#Create a folder with the file name if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$folder_name"

#Move the file to the corresponding folder
mv "$file" "$folder_name/"
done
clear
```

I receive terminal prompt `pipe while quote>` 
Why that and how to solve it?

I want to make it run but cannot understand what is going on with the prompt.

Comment: That means it thinks you're in the middle of a quoted string (which is in a `while` statement, which is in a pipe). Check to make sure your quotes are correct, especially the single-quotes. If one is missing, there's an extra one, or one has been replaced by a "fancy" unicode quote (which zsh doesn't recognize), it could cause this.

Comment: But this was working just fine in Bash. Didn't make any changes.

Comment: Try adding a `bash` shebang as your first line.... e.g. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: While you won't in general a bash script to behave the same in zsh. I don't see any issues with the script you are posted. The error message suggests some quoting problems, but there don't seem to be any. As a first debuging step, paste your whole code into a single file (say "quotetest.sh"), and run it first with `bash quotetest.sh` and then with `zsh quotetest.sh`. Do you still get an error with zsh?

Comment: @MarkSetchell : From the wording of the error message, I conclude that this code was not executed as a "script", but pasted verbatim into the command prompt.

Comment: @user1934428 Indeed. And that's the way I want to run it.

Comment: @farmaceut : It's not forbidden to run such a complex command on the prompt, although I would use a function if I had to do this more than once. However, zsh and bash are not different in this respect. If you really are in love with such monster-commands on the command line, and you still can't get it work with zsh, I suggest that you simplify the code to a minimal reproducible example and post it here again. If you are using copy and paste the command into the shell, paste it for comparision also into a text editor and have a look at it on the hexadecimal level, and check for odd hex codes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `setopt interactivecomments` to get bash-style behavior here.

By default in `zsh`, the mismatched quote in the comment will be recognized when this is pasted into the command line, and the processor will prompt for the closing quote (in this case with `for quote>` ):

```bash
for i in 1 2 3; do
  # quote: ' 
  print $i
done
```

With `setopt interactivecomments` (entered as a separate command), the text in the comment will be ignored.

The `setopt interactivecomments` statement can be added to `~/.zshrc` so that it always applies. There's some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873793/9307265).

Comment: To add to this, without interactive comments enabled, `#` is treated as a possible command name. If there hadn't been a quote-mismatch problem, you would have gotten a `command not found: #` error.