# What happens when pipe char directly followed by the redirection in Bash?

Tags: bash, pipeline

I accidentally ran the following scripts in Bash:

```
$ ls -l | > ../test.txt
```

And I got an empty test.txt.

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran a *null command*, i.e. a simple command with just one or more redirections. This performs the redirection but nothing else.

```
>file
```

is a way to truncate `file` to zero bytes. A null command ignores its stdin, which is why you don't see the `ls` output.
I believe POSIX leaves this undefined (in fact, `zsh` reads stdin when you type `>file`). There is an explicit null command named `:` (colon). Null commands are useful if you just need them for their side effects, i.e. redirection and variable assignment, as in

```
: ${FOO:="default value"}  # Assign to FOO unless it has a value already.
```

Comment: [What Is the Purpose of the `:' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Answer (score 0):

`> ../test.txt` empties the file despite of the input data that's why you've got 0-sized file.