# What does a colon do in this GNU configure script?

Tags: shell, configure

I'm looking at the differences between configure scripts for two versions of Apache and I have noticed the following in the new version of configure:

```
if [ some test ]; then :
    do this
else
    do that
```

versus the old version:

```
if [ some test ]; then
    do this
else
    do that
```

The only difference is that : (colon), no-op, after the then statement.

**Edit 1:** So the new version is basically saying:

```
if "this" then "do nothing"
    "do this"
else
    "do that"
```

What's the intent of deliberately adding that colon?

N.B. I have seen this similar question [What Is the Purpose of the `:' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) but that doesn't cover this particular scenarios.

**Edit 2:** This is visible when you compare the configure script for the Apache APR in release 2.2.17 against that in release 2.2.24.

Download the two tarballs from the [Apache site](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/) and after untarring the configure file is located in the directory httpd-2.2.x/srclib/apr for both releases.

Line 26015 in the v2.2.24 version shows this construct.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you saw this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon built-in in this case does what it always does: nothing, successfully.

You can always write a command after the `then` keyword, like this:

```
if [ some test ]; then do one thing
    do another thing
fi
```

In this particular case the author is using `:` as the first command, possibly because of the typographic effect.

Another reason to use `:` after the `then` keyword could be ensuring correctness in case lines are removed or commented in the if statement. For example this would be illegal syntax if the colon was removed:

```
if [ some test ]; then :
    # do one thing     ## Disabled due to bug #12992
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Joni, but why update the script to add that? Some versions of shell maybe?