# While loop - process substitution vs. here string with command substitution

Tags: bash, while-loop

Can someone please explain the difference between these two while loops:

```
while read test; do
echo $test
done <<< "$(seq 5)"
```

-

```
while read test; do
echo $test
done < <(seq 5)
```

Comment: Have you looked into `man bash`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
while read test; do
  echo $test
done <<< "$(seq 5)"
```

Execute `seq 5`, collecting the result into a temporary variable. Then execute the while loop, feeding it the collecting result.

```
while read test; do
  echo $test
done < <(seq 5)
```

Set up a subshell to execute `seq 5` and connect its `stdout` to `stdin`. Then start the while loop. When it finishes, restore `stdin`.

What's the difference? For `seq 5`, practically nothing; however, it can still be made visible by changing `seq 5` to `seq 5; echo done generating sequence >&2`. Then you can see that in the first case, the entire `seq` execution finishes before the `while` loop starts, while in the second case they execute in parallel.

```
$ while read n; do echo $n > /dev/stderr; done \
>       <<<"$(seq 5; echo done generating sequence >&2)"
done generating sequence
1
2
3
4
5
$ while read n; do echo $n > /dev/stderr; done \
>       < <(seq 5; echo done generating sequence >&2)
1
2
done generating sequence
3
4
5
```

If it were `seq 10000000`, the difference would be much clearer. The `<<<"$(...)` form would use a lot more memory in order to store the temporary string.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I perceive, the only difference is that process substitution would represent a named pipe e.g. `/dev/fd/63` as a file for input whereas `<<< ""` would send the input internally as if reading a buffer. Of course is the command reading the input is on another process like a subshell or another binary, then it would be sent to it like a pipe. Sometimes in environments where `process substitution` is not possible like in Cygwin, `here documents` or `here strings` along with `command substitutions` are more helpful.

If you do `echo <(:)` you see the difference in concept for process substitution over other string inputs.

Process substitution is more of representing a file, while here strings are more of sending in a buffer for input.

Comment: Can you explain why `echo <(:)` prints a file in the form of `/dev/fd/<number>`?  Is `:` a special character?

Comment: For posterity, the `:` character is an alias for the `true` command, and seems like the tersest way to demonstrate process substitution.  More information about `:` at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/2668666