# Colon used after the equal sign in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

The following is taken from the GNU ld configure file:

```
if test $ac_verc_fail = yes; then 
  LD=: critic_missing="$critic_missing ld"
fi
```

What's the meaning of the colon?

Answer (score 1):

The **`:`** is a shell builtin that is basically equivalent to the true command. It is often used as a no-op, e.g. after an if statement. Please see [this excellent reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) by [@earl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135724/earl) for more information.

Best regards 
//KH.

Comment: I had in fact read the link before I posted the question. What's misleading is the two clauses being put in a single line without a semicolon between them. I had never done that before.

Comment: In `LD=:`, colon is not a builtin, it is just a value assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative : I believe it could be a typo ...

It could be meant to be:

```
LD=; critic_missing="$critic_missing ld"
```

which is equivalent to (but less readable than):

```
LD="" ; critic_missing="$critic_missing ld"
```

That would fit better with the following statement `critic_missing="$critic_missing_ld"`  ?

(whereas in your post ld is not realling missing, it's set to ":")