# Yarn "posttest" script does not work if "test" script fails

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs, sequelize.js, yarnpkg

Well, I have these scripts in my `package.json` for testing some code in NodeJS.

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "env NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate",
    "test": "jest",
    "posttest": "env NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate:undo:all"
}
```

When the tests go clear, the "posttest" runs, but when the tests fail, I receive a

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

in VS Code. There is nothing usefull on the link about the problem, neither on the internet.

So I found this link about NPM:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5493

The guy said:

> In the vast majority of cases, users are going to be unpleasantly
> surprised if posttest runs after test failures (you don't want your
> test environment being cleaned up or new versions being published if
> there were test failures, for instance). As such, this behavior isn't
> going to change. Putting something like "test":"npm run-script
> test-failing || npm run-script mandatory-cleanup" into your
> package.json will give you what you want.

This did not solve my problem. With more research I found this:

[npm posttest doesn't trigger if npm test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292344/npm-posttest-doesnt-trigger-if-npm-test-fails)

The solutions did not work for me either.

So how can I run the "posttest" script even if the tests fail?

Comment: What exactly did not work for these solutions? This one is supposed to be applicable to your case and workable, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52073818/3731501 .

Comment: Did you mean that `npm-run-all` is supposed to work? Because it did not. I tried all the possibilities that I could think of with it, but non of then worked. Is `--continue-on-error` an argument for NPM and work for Yarn too?

Comment: Yes, it is. --continue-on-error is essential in this case. It's npm-run-all arg, not NPM. npm-run-all supports Yarn as well.

Comment: Well, I thought that `npm-run-all` was a native arg of npm, but it is a package. According with this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all there are the args `npm-run-all` and `run-s`, so I tried `"test": "npm-run-all jest posttest --continue-on-error"` and `"test": "run-s jest posttest --continue-on-error"` and in both I get `ERROR: Task not found: "jest"
error Command failed with exit code 1.`

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `jest` is not npm script so it fails. `test` and `posttest` need to be renamed, then it becomes `"test": "npm-run-all test-runme test-runafter --continue-on-error"`. This is what the answer in dupe question shows.

Comment: Oh, now I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with the conversation above, I got to this solution:

This is my scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "pretest": "env NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate",
    "run-tests": "jest",
    "run-after-tests": "env NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate:undo:all",
    "test": "npm-run-all run-tests run-after-tests --continue-on-error"
},
```

I installed the `npm-run-all` package and it runs the `run-after-test` script even if the tests fail. Now I get the errors

`error Command failed with exit code 1.`

from the `test` script, and

```
ERROR: "test" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

from `run-after-test`, but in the end my problem got solved. If someone has a better solution with no errors at the end of the scripts, please share with us.

Comment: It should be the opposite, custom `run-tests` script for `jest` and built-in `test` for npm-run-all. Otherwise `pretest` won't be matched with a cleanup automatically. The point of doing this with npm-run-all is to be able to get an error if it fails, otherwise shell `;` could be used. But it shouldn't exit with an error all the time, this means that either Jest or a clean-up failed. You can debug them separately but it seems like it's Jest.

Comment: I will have to take some more time to understand the right way, but if you can fix the code, feel free to.

Comment: Should be `"run-tests": "jest",
    "run-after-test": "env NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate:undo:all",
    "test": "npm-run-all run-tests run-after-test --continue-on-error"`.

Comment: is there an alternative for yarn? Thanks!

Comment: Later edit: nevermind. Seems like `yarn-run-all` exists, but in the package.json script you run it with `npm-run-all` . Really weird interaction, but it does the job.