# How can I use yarn workspaces to run tests for all workspaces, even if one fails?

Tags: jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspaces (yarn version 1.22.19) and I would like to run tests for all workspaces, without stopping even if tests fail for one of the workspaces.
This is so I can collect all failing tests across all workspaces in one run. I'm running the tests on a github action.

I am running the following command:
`yarn workspaces run test --passWithNoTests`
All workspaces have a `test` script in the `package.json` that runs the tests with Jest.
Jest returns an exit code of 1 when tests fail. This causes the `yarn workspaces run` command to fail and stop. I would like it to continue and fail only after running tests for all workspaces.

How can I make the `yarn workspaces run` continue even if tests fail for one of the workspaces, yet still have it fail at the end?

Edit:

I am running bash.
Using workarounds like `set -e` or `|| true` might help swallow the error, but I do want the command to fail ultimately, I just want it to fail after running all tests.

For example:

Say I have 3 workspaces - `workspace a`, `workspace b` and `workspace c`. All of them have the following script in their `package.json`:

`test: "jest"`

Say tests pass for `workspace a` and `workspace c`, but fail for `workspace b`. My desired result is that running `yarn workspaces run test` will run tests for all workspaces (and not stop after tests fail for `workspace b`) but for it to fail after running all tests.

Here is my github workflow. It just installs dependencies and runs the `test` script which runs the command `yarn workspaces run test --passWithNoTests`.

```
name: Run All Tests

on:
    pull_request:
        branches: ['develop']

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [16.x]
                # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                  node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
                  cache: 'npm'
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
            - name: Run tests
              run: yarn test
```

Comment: Please add your workflow to your question to highlight the runners and shells that you're using. If you're using `ubuntu-*` runners with the default shell i.e. bash, you can do `command || true` to return true even if `command` fails. Alternatively, if you're running multiple commands then you can disable exiting on failure with `set +e` before running those commands and then enable it i.e. `set -e`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash ignoring error for a particular command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231937/bash-ignoring-error-for-a-particular-command)

Comment: @Azeem Added some clarification. Using `set -e` or `|| true` won't fully solve what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Right. That's doable by storing Boolean output (true/false) for each step using `GITHUB_OUTPUT`  and then ANDing all the Boolean results in the last step. It would really help if you added n skeleton workflow representing your exact use case.

Comment: @Azeem I added the workflow but there's not a lot to it. It's not possible to save the output of each workflow's `yarn test` results, since for github it's just one step, it's not a step per workspace.

Comment: Oh, right. Then, it's one level above and should be configured as part of your tests. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973004/7670262. I'm not well-versed enough in this to comment and provide any guidance. You might want to include your `package.json` in your question as well. Hopefully, someone knowledgeable enough would guide you accordingly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this is what I ended up doing:

1. Add a `test:ci` script to all `package.json` file with the following defintion:

`"test:ci": "jest --ci --reporters=jest-junit --reporters=default --passWithNoTests || true"`

This makes it so the command passes even if tests fails.

2. Use a `jest-junit` test reporter to output an xml with test results.
3. In the action, run `yarn workspaces run test` which runs tests for all workspaces (packages).
4. Use the `dorny/test-reporter@v1` to collect all test result xml files into a nice view.
5. Set `fail-on-error: 'true'` for the action `dorny/test-reporter@v1` which will make the step fail if any test failed.

Here's the full github workflow:

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Build & Test

on:
    pull_request:
        branches: ['develop']

# cancel any previous runs that are still in progress if a new commit is pushed
concurrency:
    group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.event.pull_request.number || github.ref }}
    cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
    test:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [16.x]
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
              uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                  node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
                  cache: 'npm'
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
            - name: Run tests
              run: yarn test:ci
            - name: Unlink all symbolic links # so we don't go over the same file twice
              if: success() || failure() # run this step even if previous step failed
              run: find node_modules -type l -exec unlink {} \;
            - name: Test Report
              uses: dorny/test-reporter@v1
              if: success() || failure() # run this step even if previous step failed
              with:
                  name: Jest Test Results # Name of the check run which will be created
                  path: '**/jest-junit.xml'
                  reporter: jest-junit # Format of test results
                  list-suites: 'failed'
                  list-tests: 'failed'
                  fail-on-error: 'true'
```

This achieves everything I was looking for - running all tests for all workspaces, even if some fail, while still failing the workflow.