# Is function(){}() valid?

Tags: javascript

In a Javascript programming community, someone asked "How to declare anonymous method and run it immediately?" then others answered `(function(){})()` and `(function(){}())`.
People who answered `(function(){}())` says that is correct and it's possible to run, but ideone says that is wrong and I think that is incorrect.
Following links are for comparison between SpiderMonkey and Rhino.
http://ideone.com/rKaYtW
http://ideone.com/Lblb7w

Is `(function(){}())` really correct on Javascript?

Comment: Define "correct". If you mean if it's valid syntax, yes it is (only if in enclosed in parentheses as an expression).

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks, I let them know about it.

Comment: Also, your error on IDEONE was the result of leaving out a semicolon between the two IIFEs. Because you left out a semicolon and JavaScript saw that the next token was a (, it interpreted the other IIFE as an invocation of the previous function's return value with a callback, which was wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078006/iife-with-unary-operator-real-world-use-case/26078333#26078333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "but ideone says that is wrong"

If you are talking about the error in the links you show, that's because you didn't separate the two examples with a semicolon, so the second one is having its outer set of parentheses interpreted as a function call of the previous expression.

```
(function(){
    print("This is what I want.")
})() // <<< no semicolon causes the error here
(function(){
    print("This may be what I want.")
}())
```