# Colon at the beginning of line in docker entrypoint bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I was looking through [an entrypoint script for a docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cd294bf8dfdf4a74b2077aa6413fa579f9bf07de/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh) and they had the following lines (53-54)

```
: ${POSTGRES_USER:=postgres}
: ${POSTGRES_DB:=$POSTGRES_USER}
```

I saw this thread [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

and was able to figure out `:` meant true and that the `:=` was used to assign default values, but it doesn't really touch upon what does `:` at the beginning of the line at least for this specific case.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In the Bourne shell and derivatives like Bash, `:` is a no-op command: that is, it doesn't do anything, but arguments are evaluated normally.  Contrast this with a comment (`#`), which does nothing at all (everthing following the `#` is simply ignored).

This syntax:

```
: ${POSTGRES_USER:=postgres}
```

Is commonly used to assign default values to variables.  The syntax `${POSTGRES_USER:=postgres}` (a) will set the variable `POSTGRES_USER` to `postgres` **only if** it does not already have a value, and will then (b) evaluate to the value of `$POSTGRES_USER`.  If we used a comment:

```
# ${POSTGRES_USER:=postgres}
```

...nothing at all would happen, because the shell simply ignores the entire line.  Using `:` means that the `${...}` expression is still evaluated, so `POSTGRES_USER` is assigned a value if necessary.

**Update**

If there was no `:` at the beginning of the line, then this:

```
${POSTGRES_USER:=postgres}
```

would be a shell command!  The shell would first evaluate the variable expansion and come up with something like `postgres`, so you would have a shell script that effectively looked like this:

```
postgres
```

Which would probably give you the error:

```
bash: postgres: command not found...
```

Comment: Oh yeah I've seen that before when forgetting to put echo before an env variable. Okay that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It might worth noting that we **can't** use `:=` outside the `${}`, such as `POSTGRES_USER:=postgres`, as `:=` is part of the shell parameter expansion https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Great answer. Seems to me the syntax `POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}` has a lot clearer intent, is it not equivalent in "99% of cases"??

Comment: Strange, my groovy command in a pipe runs a lot more slowly when I use `:` instead of `#` (though I don't see output).