# What is the difference between writing : "${VAR_NAME:="var"}" and VAR_NAME="var" in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have seen the following syntax in a Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: "${REDIS_HOST:="redis"}"
: "${REDIS_PORT:="6379"}"
: "${REDIS_PASSWORD:=""}"
```

What is the difference to this syntax?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REDIS_HOST="redis"
REDIS_PORT="6379"
REDIS_PASSWORD=""
```

Is it a simple check such that the variable gets assigned a value if and only if the value of the variable is null before assignment? Why do we need the colon at the start of the line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-colon-dash-in-bash

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked duplicate mentions `:=` as well.

Comment: The `:` is the command being executed; assignment is a *side effect* of the expansion of the variable, so you need a context in which expansion occurs.

Comment: But why do we need the colon at the start of the line? I.e. why do we write `: "${REDIS_PASSWORD:=""}"` instead of `"${REDIS_PASSWORD:=""}"`? What does the colon at the start of the line do? The linked question doesn't answer this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342841/colon-at-the-beginning-of-line-in-docker-entrypoint-bash-script

Comment: @MoritzLoritz That's the colon I'm referring to in my comment. Without it, the result of the expansion itself would be executed as a command.