# Here is a compilation of arangodb errors

Tags: configure, arangodb

What's the problem with the configure code?

```
ERROR INFO：
./configure: line 9746: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./configure: line 9746: `else'
```

CONFIGURE CODE：

```
_ACEOF
rm -f conftest.$ac_objext
if { (ac_try="$ac_compile"
case "(($ac_try" in
  *\"* | *\`* | *\\*) ac_try_echo=\$ac_try;;
 *) ac_try_echo=$ac_try;;
esac
eval ac_try_echo="\"\$as_me:$LINENO: $ac_try_echo\""
$as_echo "$ac_try_echo") >&5
  (eval "$ac_compile") 2>conftest.er1
  ac_status=$?
  grep -v '^ *+' conftest.er1 >conftest.err
  rm -f conftest.er1
  cat conftest.err >&5
  $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  (exit $ac_status); } && {
         test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" ||
         test ! -s conftest.err
       } && test -s conftest.$ac_objext; then

else    
  $as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

        OPENSSL_WARNING=" WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or     higher"
{ $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or     higher." >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or higher." >&2;}
fi
```

Comment: What version of arangodb is that?

Comment: arangodb2.8.9 @fvu

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your configure script it seems. In the [version on Github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/2.8/configure) I see this code:

```
if ac_fn_c_try_compile "$LINENO"; then :

else
  OPENSSL_WARNING=" WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or higher"
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or higher." >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: WARNING: OpenSSL version should be 1.0.1g or higher." >&2;}

fi
```

The breaking difference with yours is that yours lacks the colon after `then`.

For a more detailed explanation about the colon operator in bash, see [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) . The short version, here it acts like some kind of "no-op".

Comment: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1339,                                                                 Can you help me take a look at this question?Is in the make arangodb 2.8.9 version there was an error   @fvu

Comment: To me it doesn't look like that issue is in any way related to the original issue of this question, you should create a new question for it. On the other hand, solving that kind of issues with the arango guys directly, as you're also doing, seems like a better strategy, imo...

Comment: In general I would recommend using ArangoDB 3.0.x. Its using cmake and is going to be the way ahead.