# What does > (greater than) exactly do at the beginning of a command line

Tags: bash, command-line

To empty out a file you can type `#> file.txt` with a > at the beginning of the command line in bash but what exactly happens here or what is the input of >?

Thank you!

Comment: Actually it would be better as `:> file.txt` which simply truncates the file. Think of it as shorthand for `echo -n "" > file.txt` or `printf "" > file.txt`.

Comment: > takes the standard output of the command on the left, and redirects it to the file on the right.

Comment: See: [**What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Comment: `#> file.txt` does nothing, it is a *comment* because of the leading `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any redirection at a bash shell is read and implemented by bash. For instance, when you execute `# ls > /tmp/ls.out` command, bash reads and parses the command and identifies redirection operator (`>`). Bash opens `/tmp/ls.out` file in write mode (which truncates the file if it exists). Then `bash` does the `pipe()-dup2()-fork()-exec()` sequence to map STDOUT filehandle of `ls` command to the open file handle to `/tmp/ls.out` file. This way `bash` achieves redirection.

In your case again, `bash` identifies that `file.txt` is a redirection target and opens it in write mode. The open() call (in write mode) truncates the `file.txt` file. Then `bash` does not find any command to execute and does nothing.

In summary, since the shell is opening target file in write mode, the existing file gets truncated. Bash does not do anything special to truncate the file.

Answer (score 0):

You're stating that you wish to feed the output of nothing (or null) to a file with the name 'file.txt '

Because you're using '>' as opposed to '>>', you're stating that the file should be replaced first if it exists.