# Difference between : and # for Bash comments

Tags: bash

Today I saw a bash script use a colon to denote a comment. What's the difference between using a colon and a hash mark?

```
: This is a comment.
# This is also a comment.
```

For one, I know you can't use a colon for a trailing comment:

```
cd somedir : This won't work as a comment.
```

But the fact that the above example works has me puzzled about how `:` is evaluated.

Comment: You may wish to read related discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin

Comment: For a trailing comment, you need to use `;:`. Just kidding, see `that other guy`'s answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:` is simply an alias for `true`, and `true` ignores its arguments:

```
# Does nothing:
true foo bar etc hello

# Does the same:
: foo bar etc hello
```

It's not a comment and should never be used as a comment, because all its arguments are still parsed and evaluated:

```
: This "comment" actually executes this command: $(touch foo)
ls -l foo
```

or like here, where StackOverflow's syntax highlighting picks up that the command in the middle is actually just text, even if a human doesn't:

```
: The command below won't run:
echo "Hello World"
: because the surrounding "comments" each contain a ' characters
```

Answer (score 1):

':' is a shell builtin command which does nothing but expands arguments and returns `true`. From the [bash man page](https://www.linux.org/docs/man5/local.html) :

```
: [arguments]
No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments
and performing any specified redirections. A zero exit code is
returned.
```

`#` is a comment. But it only works for single lines.

You can read more about ':' command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) and a better answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37411/multiline-shell-script-comments-how-does-this-work).