# git command "git checkout master || :"

Tags: git

I am trying to understand this git command.
I have got a software repository which has got submodules and that submodule points to another submodule. In order to check out, this command is used -

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout master || :'
```

This question is about understanding this command. 
What does "|| :" means in this command? I am asking this question so that I can be more flexible in changing these commands according to the need.

In this command - foreach, means for each submodule found go and do a checkout of master but what "|| and :" means here.

Answer (score 3):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive '<command>'
```

This runs the `<command>` [in each checked out submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt).

So that leaves the command itself to understand:

```
git checkout master || :
```

[`git checkout master`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) should be pretty clear.

`||` is an OR control character. For `command1 || command2`, `command2` is executed if `command1` returned a non-zero exit status. So basically when `command1` failed.

So in this case, `:` runs when `git checkout master` failed.

The colon on the other hand is an alias for `true` [in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin). So effectively, this command will not do anything, making the full command run `git checkout master` *if it can* or it will silently fail.

Answer (score 1):

`:` is a shell command that does nothing and always succeeds (similar to `true`). So by adding
`|| :` to a commandline, the overall command will always be successful, even if the command on the left side of the `||` failed. In this case it causes `git submodule foreach` to continue even if one of the submodules isn't able to checkout `master`.

This usage is suggested by the git documentation:

> A non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding `|| :` to the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd ||:` is just a way to ensure that the command always succeeds.  If cmd fails, then `:` is executed and succeeds, so that `$?` will always be 0.  So basically your submodule foreach is ignoring any errors checking out master.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`git submodule` docs for `foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt)...

> *A non-zero return from the command in any submodule causes the processing to terminate. This can be overridden by adding || : to the end of the command.*

It says to keep processing submodules even if the command fails on one of them.

If you're familiar with `make`, it's similar to [putting a `-` at the front of a command then `make` will then ignore any errors from that command](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#index-_002d-_0028in-recipes_0029).

Answer (score 0):

`command_a || command_b` leads bash to execute command_b only if command_a was **not** executed successfully (command_a returns exit code diffrent to 0). `:` is an alternative notation for `true` which is equal to exit code 0

So `git checkout master || :` will always return true even if `git checkout master` failed.

Just writing `git submodule foreach --recursive 'git checkout master'` would interrupt if the checkout was not successful for one of the submodules.