# Logical OR (||) followed by colon in Bash

Tags: bash

I know what the operators `&&` and `||` do in Bash.

But recently I came across the following case in a shell script:

```
[[ test1 ]] && { test2 } || :
```

I am confused as to what does the `|| :` (logical OR followed by `:`) in the above statement does?

Could anyone elaborate?

Comment: [`:` is a command that does nothing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon), so `command || :` is just a way to ‘ignore’ that `command` may fail. Especially useful with `set -e`.

Answer (score 3):

**One step at a time**:

- `:` is a shell builtin that is basically equivalent to the `true` command. If you're interested, there is a very good description of it's history and how it works on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/2068165).
- `[[ test1 ]]` tests for the presence of `test1`. (Normally, this would be a variable.)
- `{ test2 }` executes `test2` in the current shell environment. (Normally, this would be a list of commands terminated with a newline or semicolon.)
- `&&` has a higher precedence then `||`. Thus `[[ test1 ]] && { test2 }` will be evaluated before `||`.

**Putting it all together**,

```
[[ test1 ]] && { test2 } || :
```

Means:

- If `test1` exists, then execute `test2`
- If `test1` doesn't exists, or if `test2` fails, then return `true` (ie: `$? == 0`)

**Things to note**:

- returned exit code (`$?`) is not the same as "return no errors"! If `test2` fails, you might still see errors in the script's output, but the exit code of the entire command will always be `true`.
- Errors when executing `test2` will not terminate the script if it is executed under `set -e`.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd || :` is a way to ignore an error caused by `cmd`. This is useful if the script is executed using `set -e` and you don't want it to be interrupted if `cmd` fails.