# Assignment of "$*"

Tags: shell

I have come across an assignment like this which I have never seen before, "`: ${var=$*}`". The assignment can also be done like `var=$*`, but can anyone explain about the above what is being done. I tried to search for it but got nothing.

Comment: Bash manual: [special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) for `$*`; [Bourne shell built-in commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) for `:` command; [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for `${var=$*}`.  Although I cited the Bash manual, for this notation, a Korn shell manual would give the same information; so would the POSIX shell specification.

Answer (score 1):

Explication:

For example:

```
    A="value1"
    B=${A="value2"}
    echo $B  ->  value1
```

Now, when the variable A is not defined, it retrieves the value 'value2'

```
    unset A
    B=${A="value2"}    
    echo $B  ->  value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at this line step by step:

- **`: argument`** : This only executes the expansions of argument. The colon command is generally not useful, but can be used for parameter validation or initialisation via parameter expansion. It is also used to run infinite while loops.

  - [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)
  - [[U&L] What purpose does the colon builtin serve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31673/)
  - [BashFAQ035](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)
- **`${var=word}`** The `argument` in the above expansion is of the form `${var=word}`. This is identical to `${var:=word}` with the only difference that the former tests if `var` is unset while the latter tests if `var` is unset or null. If the condition applies, `var` is assigned with the value of `word`
- **`$*`** The value of `word` in the above is now the expansion of `$*`. It expands to a single string of the form `$1c$2c$3c...$` where `$n` are the values of the command arguments and the value of `c` expands to the first character of the variable `IFS`.

Having this all said, this command is equivalent to the following line which uses classic programming jargon:

```
if [ -z ${var+x} ]; then var="$*"; fi
```

See [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515)

Comment: The compact notation is very readble — more so than the `if` statement — once you are familiar with it.  Especially as you're using an alternative to `${var=val}` in the `if`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are correct. I've rewritten the sentence a bit.