# BASH comments: Difference between # (hash) -vs- : (colon) commenting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command, comments

In bash **GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)** or any stable one,
You can use `#` or `:` to comment

What's the difference between these 2 and usefulness?

I noticed `#` comment makes the whole line a comment, while `:` scope/effect is only until it reaches the first `\n` or `;` character (in a given line).

```
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ # this is a # comment; echo this will not print
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ : this is a : comment; echo this will print
this will print
```

In the following code, why the last 2 comments didn't work as expected to treat them as a comment then (albeit `::` works if it comes after a `:` ?

```
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ #
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ ##
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ ####
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ ####
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ : : : : : : : : : :
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ #
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ # # #
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ ####
[gigauser@someserver ~]$
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ :
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ : :
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ : : : : : : : : : : : : ::::::::
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ : : :::::
[gigauser@someserver ~]$
[gigauser@someserver ~]$
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ ::
-bash: ::: command not found
[gigauser@someserver ~]$ :::::
-bash: :::::: command not found
[gigauser@someserver ~]$
```

Comment: You *can* use `:` but it's not meant for comments. `#` is made for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin)

Comment: @micke That post is very good but only focuses on `:` (`bash null command`) not sure if it gives comparison. I also found this post: https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/null-command/ BASH `NULL COMMAND`

Comment: Yes I meant to highlight that while it's certainly possible to comment with `:`. It's not it's purpose, a bad idea and against all and any style guides. 
See: https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/comments/#5-using-unconventional-block-comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:` isn't a comment at all, it's a command that doesn't do anything. The most important difference is that since it's a command, any shell syntax after it will be interpreted and acted on. For example:

```
: Check whether x > 1
```

Here the `> 1` part will be interpreted as an output redirection, so it'll create a file named "1" and redirect the (empty) output to it. If it'd been `x < 1` it would've tried to open "1" for input and (probably) failed.

```
: Check permissions on the user's home directory
```

Here the `'` will be interpreted as starting a single-quoted string (which'll be an argument to `:`), and will probably wreak havoc with how the rest of the script is parsed.

```
: Test for completion (again)
```

Produces `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``

The `:` command is sometimes useful if you want parameter expansions to be performed (because of their side effects), but don't want to do anything with the result.

```
: ${VAR:=defaultvalue}
```

Here, if `$VAR` isn't already set to something nonblank, the `:=` modifier will set it to "defaultvalue". This is basically a shorthand for

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ]; then
    VAR=defaultvalue
fi
```

---

**Edit:**

As AKS pointed out with [a link in the comments](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/comments/#5-using-unconventional-block-comments), one effect of `:` is that you can make block comments with it and a here-document with a quoted delimiter. That makes a functional difference from `#`.

```sh
: <<'COMMENT'
This block doesn't do anything, effectively a multi line comment block.
It'll also not get identified by linters and syntax highlighters as a comment.
COMMENT
```

Regular comments would have to start each line with `#`.

(Note: contrary to what the link says, you can use either single- or double-quotes on the here-doc delimiter, i.e. either `<'COMMENT'` or `<"COMMENT"`. Without some sort of quoting on the delimiter, the shell will try to parse and expand any `$` or backtick expressions it finds in the document, which can again cause trouble.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.