# What is the purpose of the ":" (colon) in 'trap : TERM INT; ...'

Tags: bash, shell, built-in

I found some sample code to keep a docker build container running until it gets stopped.
It uses

```sh
/bin/ash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

as parameter.

Why  is the ':' needed? [Another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) mentions the colon is just used for side effects, but here I'd assume TERM INT is needed as a trap argument.

Comment: [The Bash manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) might be useful. Especially its [list of builtin commands](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS).

Comment: Since `ash` is Posix compliant: The [`trap`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) function states that the [null-utility colon (`:`)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16) is an action. So in the end, it does nothing when TERM or INT are signalled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` is the command that will be executed on receipt of TERM or INT.  It is a noop, so basically you can think of it as if the signals are ignored.