# What does the colon in ": exit 0" do?

Tags: bash, exit

I have a bash script which ends with:

```
: exit 0
```

I understand that the colon is a bash built-in NOP command.

What is the point of passing it an argument of `exit 0`?

Comment: Probably a non-standard way to comment it out?

Comment: The return status of `:` is zero, so there is a difference compared to `#` (commenting it out).

Comment: Perhaps the programmer was too lazy to write it as `: # exit 0`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` builtin just ignores any arguments, so it's essentially just a way to comment except the arguments will be expanded. So in many cases the result [might be different](https://superuser.com/q/423980/241386) from a simple comment

```
: whatever command arguments can follow the ":"
: this will have side $(echo effect >file.txt)
```

That means in this case it's just useless. The return value is the same in both `: exit 0` and `exit 0`

From the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section in [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> `: [arguments]`:
>
> No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections. The return status is zero.

It has some other useful purposes that you can read in [What is the purpose of the : (colon) GNU Bash builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3224878/995714), for example to begin a block comment