# what is ":" called in bash? Colon usage as a pass statement

Tags: bash

See: [What is the Bash equivalent of Python's pass statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421586/what-is-the-bash-equivalent-of-pythons-pass-statement)

What is this ":" colon usage called? For example:

```
if [[ -n $STRING ]]; then
    #printf "[INFO]:STRING: if -n string: STRING:$STRING \n"
    : 
else
    printf "[INFO]:Nothing in the the string\n"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To what that is, run `help :` in the shell. It gives:

> ```
> $ help :
> :: :
>     Null command.
>
>     No effect; the command does nothing.
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Always succeeds.
> ```

Very useful in one-liner infinite loops, for example:

```
while :; do date; sleep 1; done
```

Again, you could write the same thing with `true` instead of `:`, but this is shorter.

Interestingly:

> ```
> $ help true
> true: true
>     Return a successful result.
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Always succeeds.
> ```

According to this, the difference is that `:` is "Null command",
while `true` is "Returns a successful result".
Another difference is that `true` is usually a real binary:

> ```
> $ which true
> /usr/bin/true
> ```

On the other hand, `which :` gives nothing. (Which makes sense, being a "null command".)

Anyway, [@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy) is right, this is duplicate of [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin), which explains it much better.